# android saving 3 bitmaps as 1

Tags: java, android, image-processing, bitmap

I've an app that takes a picture. It creates 2 subset bitmaps, processes these bitmaps with a distortion, then places the subsets over the original as overlays. Is there a way to save all three bitmaps as one (as it appears on the phone's screen)? I'd like to save what the user sees on the screen as a fourth bitmap on the sdcard? I've a feeling I've done this wrong.

Thanks

[update1]

```
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Log.e(TAG, "******about to draw bgr ");
        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);

        if (isLocked == true && bothCirclesInPlace == true){
            if(overLay != null)
             canvas.drawBitmap(overLay, centreX-radius, centreY-radius, null);
            if(overLay2 != null)
             canvas.drawBitmap(overLay2, centreA-radius, centreB-radius, null);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to overlay multiple bitmaps and save as a single image file (PNG / JPEG / ..).

One way is to use Canvas class. Canvas along with Paint class defines the way in which bitmaps are overlayed.

Following code will demonstrate multiple bitmap overlay into a single image file.

```
try {
        // String mFilePath  : Absolute Path of the file to be saved 

        // Bitmap mBitmap1   : First bitmap. This goes as background.
        // Bitmap mCBitmap   : Bitmap associated with the Canvas. All draws on the canvas are drawn into this bitmap.
        // Bitmap mBitmap2   : Second bitmap. This goes on top of first (in this example serves as foreground.

        // Paint mPaint1     : Paint to draw first bitmap
        // Paint mPaint2     : Paint to draw second bitmap on top of first bitmap

        Bitmap mCBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap1.getWidth(), mBitmap1.getHeight(), mBitmap1.getConfig());

        Canvas tCanvas = new Canvas(mCBitmap);

        tCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap1, 0, 0, mPaint1);

        mPaint2.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN));
        // XFer modes define the overlay characteristic

        tCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap2, 0, 0, mPaint2);

        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(mFilePath);
        mCBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

        stream.flush();
        stream.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("Could not save", e.toString());
}
```

Shash

Comment: Hi, thanks for that code. can i ask a question though. Is it good/normal practice to have i/o code within the onDraw() method or should it be separated away somehow? sorry but i'm new to Android:)

Comment: I am using this code to save a bitmap that was generated on a DrawableView ( https://github.com/PaNaVTEC/DrawableView ) and the PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN line was causing the bitmap from the drawableView not to be saved with the original image. Removing that line solved the issue, thank you for the code, it's pretty easy

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following.
If you can, draw the images to a canvas:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(// Set the params you like //);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

canvas.drawBitmap(// The first picture //);
canvas.drawBitmap(// First overlay //);
canvas.drawBitmap(// Second overlay //);
// You can draw whatever you like
// For example:
canvas.drawRectangle(...);

// Now the bitmap can will hold everything you draw on the canvas.
// You can save the bitmap to the SD
bitmap.compress(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bitma.compress(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) with [FileOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) as last argument.

Read about [external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) for instructions on how to write to sd-card.

Comment: hi, i can write to sdcard already and my app already uses that bitmap method you suggest. the thing is my display now has 3 bitmaps in it to make the desired effect. i know how to save one image just not 3. i've updated my post with my onDraw