# How to display my pic into my own frame after taking snap from my camera

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

Here is my code, it's using the camera and those snaps are stored into the SD card, this is working perfectly. Now I need to get those snaps back into my own frame. How do I do that, suggestion anyone?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CampicsaveActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ImageView iv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camdemo);

        iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {     
                saveImage(0);   
            } });    

 }

 public void saveImage(int IMAGE_CAPTURE)
 {

     try {

         FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(
            "MyFile.jpeg", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
         fos.close();
         File f = new File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + "MyFile.jpeg");

         Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
         intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
         intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION,90);
         startActivityForResult(intent,IMAGE_CAPTURE);
         startActivityForResult(new Intent(
            MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).putExtra(
                MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f)),IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        }
        catch(IOException e) {

        }
    }  
}
```

Here is my camera.xml

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >



           <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="@drawable/kk" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make `Bitmap` objects of both the Overlay and the Snapped Image...

Then to combine them, use this snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7303866/216517) The example uses Mode.DARKEN. Experiment with different modes until you get your desired result.